# VB.NET code to reverse file contents

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have wrote some code in Visual Basic 6 which reverses the contents of a file, however I have problems converting this code to .NET as VB.NET only reads the text part of the file. Can someone please show me the VB.NET equivalent of this code. I believe it will not only help me, but the whole SOF community :).

```
Public Function NeutralizeFile(strFile As String, strOut As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrDelete
Dim File As String
Open strFile For Binary As #1
File = Space(LOF(1))
Get #1, , File
Close #1
File = StrReverse(File)
Open strOut For Binary As #1
Put #1, , File
Close #1
Kill strFile
ErrDelete:
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub NeutralizeFile(ByVal PathIn As String, ByVal PathOut As String)
    Try
        Dim data() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathIn)
        Array.Reverse(data)
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(PathOut, data)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Sub NeutralizeFile(strFile As String, strOut As String)
    Try
        Dim StreamReader1 As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
        Dim StreamWriter1 As New IO.StreamWriter(strOut)

        StreamWriter1.Write(StrReverse(StreamReader1.ReadToEnd))

        StreamReader1.Close()
        StreamReader1.Dispose()

        StreamWriter1.Close()
        StreamWriter1.Dispose()

        IO.File.Delete(strFile)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```